# HTML/CSS - centering floated content

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to center a group of float-arranged contents'.
If the general area gets smaller they are supposed jump to the next line grouped, forwhat i also grouped them into dividerblocks.

Code:

```
<dif id="mainframe">
  <dif id="centeringframe">
    <dif id="dividerblock">
      <dif id="contentblock">
        <p>content 1</p>
      </dif>
      <dif id="contentblock">
        <p>content 2</p>
      </dif>
    </dif>
    <dif id="dividerblock">
      <dif id="contentblock">
        <p>content 3</p>
      </dif>
      <dif id="contentblock">
        <p>content 4</p>
      </dif>
   </dif>
  </dif>
</dif>
```

StyleSheet:

```
#mainframe {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:center;
}
#centeringframe {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
#dividerblock {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-color: green;
}
#contentblock {
  float:left;
  width: 80px;
  height:80px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kwbq4on/

This works fine as long as all 4 contents fit into a single line.
The moment content 3&4 are passed into a second line the general centering fails.

How can be ensured the centeringframe adapts its size to to the new arangement of contents/-dividers?

Answer (score 0):

put another div over your floated content. make it center using (margin: 0 auto;)

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="float:left">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sry, but i dont get the point of your Idea.
The centeringframe allready contains all contents while beeing centered inside mainframe.